# xslt recursive multiplication

Tags: xslt

The xml document below represents 3 number, 2, 2 and 2. A node `<s>` is counted as a number and ended with `<zero/>`.

```
    <?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
    <nat xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:noNamespaceSchemaLocation="nat.xsd">
      <s>
        <s>
          <zero/>
        </s>
      </s>
      <s>
        <s>
          <zero/>
        </s>
      </s>
      <s>
        <s>
          <zero/>
        </s>
      </s>
    </nat>
```

I just started learning with xslt and this is one of the exercise for recursion. I could do plus recursively for adding up all numbers but this multiplying more than two number just blows my mind. I have no idea how to do it.

The expected answer for above xml doc is 8s(ignore the format) :

`<s><s><s><s><s><s><s><s><zero/></s></s></s></s></s></s></s></s>`
My idea was this, I can have a template to do multiplication for two number by adding. So for this 2x2x2, I would do the 2nd 2 times the 3rd 2 that returns 4 and finally do 2*4. But call template don't return value in xslt unlike java or scheme so I appreciate any hints/helps.

**Update:**
I got my answer by adding in a print template to Dimitre's answer. Here it is:

```
    <xsl:template name="print">
    <xsl:param name="pAccum"/>
        <xsl:choose>
            <xsl:when test="$pAccum > 0">
                <s>
                    <xsl:call-template name="print">
                        <xsl:with-param name="pAccum" select="$pAccum - 1"/>
                    </xsl:call-template>
                </s>
             </xsl:when>
             <xsl:otherwise>
                <zero/>
            </xsl:otherwise>    
        </xsl:choose>
</xsl:template>
```

Comment: This doesn't seem a suitable exercise for recursion -- why don't you try a simpler and more clear problem? Have: `<nums><num>2</num>><num>3</num>><num>4</num>><num>5</num></nums>` and find the product of all `num` elements.

Comment: Your comment about templates makes it sound as if you want to do this in XSLT 1.0. If you really need to use a version of the language that has been superseded for nearly 6 years, you should say so in your post. Then those of us for whom XSLT 1.0 is a distant fading memory needn't bother answering.

Comment: @MichaelKay: ouch, I'm sorry for the vague comment. This is meant for XSLT 2.0. As I was just thinking out loud when I tried to solve this problem.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**This transformation**:

```
<xsl:stylesheet version="1.0"
 xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform">
 <xsl:output omit-xml-declaration="yes" indent="yes"/>

 <xsl:template match="/">
  <xsl:call-template name="product">
   <xsl:with-param name="pArgs" select="//zero"/>
  </xsl:call-template>
 </xsl:template>

 <xsl:template name="product">
  <xsl:param name="pAccum" select="1"/>
  <xsl:param name="pArgs" select="/.."/>

  <xsl:choose>
   <xsl:when test="not($pArgs)">
    <xsl:value-of select="$pAccum"/>
   </xsl:when>
   <xsl:otherwise>
    <xsl:call-template name="product">
     <xsl:with-param name="pAccum"
          select="$pAccum * count($pArgs[1]/ancestor::s)"/>
     <xsl:with-param name="pArgs" select="$pArgs[position() > 1]"/>
    </xsl:call-template>
   </xsl:otherwise>
  </xsl:choose>
 </xsl:template>
</xsl:stylesheet>
```

**when applied on the provided XML document:**

```
<nat>
    <s>
        <s>
            <zero/>
        </s>
    </s>
    <s>
        <s>
            <zero/>
        </s>
    </s>
    <s>
        <s>
            <zero/>
        </s>
    </s>
</nat>
```

**produces the wanted, correct result:**

```
8
```

**Explanation**:

Primitive recursion with stop condition -- empty argument node-set and an accumulator - parameter for passing the currently accumulated result to the next recursive call.

Comment: +1 for correct answer but instead of displaying 8 it should display <s><s><s><s><s><s><s><s><zero/></s></s></s></s></s></s></s></s>. There are 8 <s> and <zero/> to indicate the end.

Comment: Thanks! it works out nicely. I ran your solution through debugger and added in the template to get the correct representation for the answer. See my edit above!

Comment: @bili: You are welcome. Yes, I completely ignored this rather strange format. I wasn't aware you wanted an XSLT 2.0 solution -- in such case it is more convenient to use `xsl:finction` . Also, if you are interested in this topic, you might find it interesting reading about FXSL: http://conferences.idealliance.org/extreme/html/2006/Novatchev01/EML2006Novatchev01.html

Answer (score 1):

In XSLT 2.0 I would start with a pair of functions:

```
<xsl:function name="f:toNumber" as="xs:integer">
  <xsl:param name="z" as="element(zero)"/>
  <xsl:sequence select="count($z/ancestor::*)"/>
</xsl:function>

<xsl:function name="f:fromNumber" as="element()>
  <xsl:param name="z" as="xs:integer"/>
  <xsl:choose>
   <xsl:when test="$z=0"><zero/></xsl:when>
   <xsl:otherwise><s><xsl:sequence select="f:fromNumber($z - 1)"/>
</xsl:function>
```

That tackles the weirdness of your numeric representation.

Now you just need a function that computes the product of a sequence of numbers:

```
<xsl:function name="f:product" as="xs:integer">
  <xsl:param name="in" as="xs:integer"/>
  <xsl:sequence select="if (count($in) = 1) then $in[1] else $in * f:product($in[position()>1])"/>
</xsl:function>
```

and the rest is child's play...